# nvidia-cuda-toolkit ? not compatible with nvidia-495 driver

Tags: nvidia, cuda, 21.10

When trying to install nvidia-cuda-toolkit (on ubuntu 21.10 with the nvidia-495 diver) I am asked to remove the nvidia driver. Why?

```
~> sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dkms libnvidia-cfg1-495 libnvidia-fbc1-495 libnvidia-fbc1-495:i386
  libnvidia-gl-495 libxnvctrl0 nvidia-dkms-495 nvidia-kernel-common-495
  nvidia-prime nvidia-settings screen-resolution-extra
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-495
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  g++-10 libaccinj64-11.3 libcub-dev libcublas11 libcublaslt11 libcudart11.0
  libcufft10 libcufftw10 libcuinj64-11.3 libcupti-dev libcupti-doc
  libcupti11.3 libcurand10 libcusolver11 libcusolvermg11 libcusparse11
  libegl-dev libgl-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libgles-dev libgles1 libglvnd-core-dev
  libglvnd-dev libglx-dev libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libnppc11
  libnppial11 libnppicc11 libnppidei11 libnppif11 libnppig11 libnppim11
  libnppist11 libnppisu11 libnppitc11 libnpps11 libnvblas11
  libnvidia-compute-470 libnvidia-ml-dev libnvjpeg11 libnvrtc-builtins11.3
  libnvrtc11.2 libnvtoolsext1 libnvvm4 libopengl-dev libopengl0
  libpthread-stubs0-dev libstdc++-10-dev libthrust-dev libvdpau-dev libx11-dev
  libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev node-html5shiv nsight-compute
  nsight-compute-target nsight-systems nsight-systems-target nvidia-cuda-dev
  nvidia-cuda-gdb nvidia-cuda-toolkit-doc nvidia-opencl-dev nvidia-profiler
  nvidia-visual-profiler ocl-icd-opencl-dev opencl-c-headers
  opencl-clhpp-headers x11proto-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Suggested packages:
  g++-10-multilib gcc-10-doc libstdc++-10-doc libvdpau-doc libx11-doc
  libxcb-doc opencl-clhpp-headers-doc
Recommended packages:
  libnvcuvid1
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libnvidia-compute-495 libnvidia-compute-495:i386 libnvidia-decode-495
  libnvidia-decode-495:i386 libnvidia-encode-495 libnvidia-encode-495:i386
  nvidia-compute-utils-495 nvidia-driver-495 nvidia-utils-495
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  g++-10 libaccinj64-11.3 libcub-dev libcublas11 libcublaslt11 libcudart11.0
  libcufft10 libcufftw10 libcuinj64-11.3 libcupti-dev libcupti-doc
  libcupti11.3 libcurand10 libcusolver11 libcusolvermg11 libcusparse11
  libegl-dev libgl-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libgles-dev libgles1 libglvnd-core-dev
  libglvnd-dev libglx-dev libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libnppc11
  libnppial11 libnppicc11 libnppidei11 libnppif11 libnppig11 libnppim11
  libnppist11 libnppisu11 libnppitc11 libnpps11 libnvblas11
  libnvidia-compute-470 libnvidia-ml-dev libnvjpeg11 libnvrtc-builtins11.3
  libnvrtc11.2 libnvtoolsext1 libnvvm4 libopengl-dev libopengl0
  libpthread-stubs0-dev libstdc++-10-dev libthrust-dev libvdpau-dev libx11-dev
  libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev node-html5shiv nsight-compute
  nsight-compute-target nsight-systems nsight-systems-target nvidia-cuda-dev
  nvidia-cuda-gdb nvidia-cuda-toolkit nvidia-cuda-toolkit-doc
  nvidia-opencl-dev nvidia-profiler nvidia-visual-profiler ocl-icd-opencl-dev
  opencl-c-headers opencl-clhpp-headers x11proto-dev xorg-sgml-doctools
  xtrans-dev
0 upgraded, 73 newly installed, 9 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,829 MB of archives.
After this operation, 4,523 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: I doubt the CUDA code cares, but the deb packages were set up with some really unfortunate dependencies.  See Answer 1077061 for a description of using Intel's .run script for the installation, allowing you to: 1)select your location instead of a system area,2)skip the Nvidia driver install.